# Another 'me' versus 'myself' usage question

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, reflexives, indirect-objects

I am quitting a job. I wrote a letter of resignation and have come upon the following sentence:

"Moreover, I believe [name of restaurant] will be better suited to have an employee that is different than me/myself."

Initially I wrote 'myself' because I am the subject and the 'myself' refers to me as an indirect object. So is it correct to use 'myself'? Or do I simply keep it as 'me'?

Comment: (1) Don't use _myself_. (2) Use _different from_, not _different than_. (3) The sentence is way too complex; say _will work better with a different employee_, thereby not having to refer to yourself at all, and saving lots of processing time.

Comment: I'd drop the entire sentence. Your thoughts on how the restaruant would survive your loss aren't germane.  You can leave even if they must close due to your irreplacableness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you shorten it up - something like

> Moreover, I believe [name of restaurant] will be better off without me.

or

> Moreover, I believe I am no longer a good match for the position of [current title] at [name of restaurant].